# Javascript to get value from a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

l want to reach span value as a int

```
 <span id="astar"> @item.CommentId</span>
```

this is my span and l showing commentid here
and l need to reach this id from script side

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#reply").click(function () {

        var r_comment = $("#replytext").val();
        var r_commentid = $(".astar").val();

        console.log(r_comment);
        console.log(r_commentid);

});
})
```

l can reach the replytext is fine but when l want to see r_commentid 
console says undefinied

Comment: `$("#astar").text()` or `$("#astar").html()` the choice is up to you!

Comment: You seem to know already how to select by id in jQuery using `#` and otherwise please use the search feature in google or SO to find How To Get a value from a span. If in addition you need to get the value as an integer for further use, please see "How to convert a string to int" on google or SO.

Comment: `parseInt($('#astar').text())` is what you probably want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Since span has `id`. So use `#` instead of `.`

2.Use `.html()` or `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Like below:-

```
var r_commentid = $("#astar").html();
```

***A sample example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#reply").click(function () {
    var r_comment = $("#replytext").html();
    var r_commentid = $("#astar").html();
    console.log(r_comment);
    console.log(r_commentid);
    
    var r_comment1 = $("#replytext").text();
    var r_commentid1 = $("#astar").text();
    console.log(r_comment1);
    console.log(r_commentid1);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="astar">1</span>
<span id="replytext">Hey changed jQuery code is working fine now!</span>

<button id="reply">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: .html() worked thanks a lot

Comment: l marked  l am new on stackoverflow  :) and thanks again

Comment: @OguzDemir  glad to help you:):)